# Java get resource InvalidJarIndexException

Tags: java, log4j

I have a class names test.java and another file "log4j.properties" in the same folder but following call

```
getClass().getResource("log4j.properties")
```

fails with

```
ms
Trace:
sun.misc.InvalidJarIndexException: Invalid index
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.findResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getResource(Unknown Source)
```

But getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("log4j.properties") works. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InvalidJarIndexException` is normally caused by a corrupt `INDEX.LIST` file in the JAR. So check the JAR for any problems. See http://littletechsecrets.wordpress.com/2008/12/01/why-does-invalidjarindexexception-occur/

The different results you describe are probably related to `Class.getResource()` resolving a path relative to the classes package, and `ClassLoader.getResource()` resolving a path relative to the root. So `getClass().getResource("/log4j.properties")` might fix your problem.

Comment: I do not have INDEX.LIST in my jar. And class isn't it Class.getResource() is supposed to check the current package directory for the resource file?